# Django Deploy Reccomendations

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Web application provided in SaaS way... (each client has his own sub-domain and his own database).

My app uses Django Python and Postgresql.

Right now is hosted on a linux shared hosting plan, using Apache, and mod_wsgi, but I am migrating to a Linux VPS next month, and have read about Nginx and Gunicorn (also uwsgi) being a better way to go... I want to know your recommendations about deploying django.

I am mainly developer so I have a little background on sysadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit of using Nginx as your web server is the smaller memory footprint compared to Apache, essential when you're running a resource constrained VPS.

Regarding the WSGI recommendation, you have a lot of good options, uWSGI and Gunicorn being two of them.

I've tried both but I ended up using FAPWS3 instead because of the more strait forward setup with Nginx. Using a Python virtual environment and an instance of Supervisord to keep an eye on the daemons, the setup has been running for over a year. So definitely recommended.

- http://www.fapws.org/
- http://supervisord.org/

Comment: I had trouble getting WSGI working (probably my problem, not WSGI's) and wound up using Nginx to proxy to Apache/`mod_python` with memcached in between. Apache runs pretty light because it only needs to render pages in the event of a cache miss, and Nginx handles the asset serving as well.